# How to write condition in iam policy terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to convert this piece of CloudFormation code in Terraform.

```
 - !If
    - ResourceLambdaNameProvided
    - Sid: "AllowLambdaInvokeFunction"
      Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Resource: !Split
        - ","
        - !Ref ResourceLambdaName
    - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

The code above signifies that the Parameter `ResourceLambdaName` can be left blank if you
don't provide any value. For example if you keep the value blank it will not add the access else it will provide the access for a given lambda function and similar I want to do in terraform.

Can someone help me in figuring out the right syntax for it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual TF code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to share code of what you have tried so far.
Assuming that you have an IAM role for lambda, I'll share few points that you can work on implementing:

1. Create [IAM policy resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy) for lambda:InvokeFunction access.
2. Create [IAM policy attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy_attachment) with count set to zero when ResourceLambdaName is empty, and set count to 1 when ResourceLambdaName is not empty. You can use [conditional experession](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals) to achieve this.

Comment: resource "aws_iam_policy" "sf_base_policy" {
  name        = "sf_execution_policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "step functions base policy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      
      {
        Sid = "LambdaInvokeFunction"
        Action = [
          "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}